# How do I unwrap PLSQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

How do I unwrap PLSQL functions/procedures written in Oracle 9.2?

Comment: What is a wrapped PLSQL function?

Comment: @Janek Bogucki - http://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/3382331/Oracles-Wrap-Utility.htm