# are there any ways to reverse engineer Oracle trigger or sort of decompile it?

Tags: oracle, triggers, reverse-engineering

Are there any way to decompile or reverse engineer Oracle trigger?  Any tools available, any free ones?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This may be done querying user_triggers or dba_triggers as such:

> SELECT trigger_body FROM user_triggers where trigger_name = 'THENAME';

or

> SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TRIGGER','....') FROM DUAL

If the trigger code calls other code that  is [Wrapped](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db102/print_hit_summary?search_string=wrap) (obsufacted) you will need to unwrap it, see [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045208/how-do-i-unwrap-plsql) or do a google search for "oracle unwrap pl/sql"

You can also use a [Oracle managment or development too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222531/good-oracle-database-development-and-management-tool-on-windows/3222557#3222557)l to get the trigger source code.

Comment: Thanks!

And to get it from a different user if permissions allow:

select trigger_name, status, trigger_body from all_triggers WHERE owner = 'SOMEUSERNAME' ORDER BY trigger_name;

Comment: And it seems SQLTools may extract trigger body with not problem, just with a double click.

Anyway thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Sql*plus should be able to solve that.  You can query the system tables to get the body text.